# How to extract substring from a String from specific String to Specific end?

Tags: php

How can I extract specific sub string from a Main String from specific string to specific end String. Like I have below path

> your path is D:///path/to/required/directory/sample/subdirectory/a/b/abc/sample.text

from above path I want to extract sub string from `/sample` to `abc`. In detail

> /sample/subdirectory/a/b/abc

I tried with other substring functions but no success.

Can anybody help me for this?

I had tried with one of example given in php.net site

```
function reverse_strrchr($haystack, $needle, $trail)
{
        return strrpos($haystack, $needle) ? substr($haystack, 0, strrpos($haystack, $needle) + $trail) : false;
}
```

but it gives me below path but I want to start from `/sample` to end

> your path is
>   D:///path/to/required/directory/sample/subdirectory/a/b/abc

Comment: Is the path likely to be static at all times or will this function be used to grab files from multiple locations?

Comment: @ChrisBertrand No. It will be dynamic every time but `/sample` will always be available in path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You start from position 0.

```
substr($haystack, 0, strrpos($haystack, $needle) + $trail)
```

Search the position of /sample and replace it with 0.

For example:

```
$haystack = -- your path here --;
$result = substr($haystack, strrpos($haystack, "/sample"), strrpos($haystack, "abc"));
echo $result; // Your new "path"
```

Comment: I tried with strpos($str","/sample") but not giving proper position.

Comment: Thanks for quick and perfect reply. I have just modified your version. Like `$str = (reverse_strrchr($str, "/", 0));$result = substr($str, strrpos($str, "/sample"));` and now it's giving me a path what I needed. I appreciate it ;)

Comment: Check my answer below will be helpful

Answer (score 2):

I think you would like this.
It is proper what you need is.

Your Main String is:
D:///path/to/required/directory/sample/subdirectory/a/b/abc/sample.text

You want to Start Extract From "/sample" ( First "sample" word )

You want to Stop Extract To "/sample" ( Last "sample" word )

Will return the following string as Answer
"/sample/subdirectory/a/b/abc/sample"

```
$mainstr = "D:///path/to/required/directory/sample/subdirectory/a/b/abc/sample.text";
$needle = "/sample";
$trail  = "/sample";

echo $this->reverse_strrchr($mainstr, $needle, $trail);
```

Function definition is:

```
function reverse_strrchr($haystack, $needle, $trail)
{
    $start  = strpos($haystack, $needle);
    $total  = strrpos($haystack, $trail) - strpos($haystack, $needle) + strlen($trail);
    $result = substr($haystack, $start, $total);
    return $result;
}
```